# Are any drugs approved to deal with drug-induced myoclonus?

Tags: seizure

I was reading about [lamotrigine (Lamictal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamotrigine), an anticonvulsant, and came across a claim (which has been [partially verified](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16157917)) that it can cause [myoclonic jerks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myoclonus) in some cases. Myoclonus can be treated with various drugs, some of which are anticonvulsants. It would make sense to switch a patient to a different anticonvulsant if myoclonic jerks persist, but if treatment with lamotrigine was continued, a second drug *could* be prescribed to deal with the jerks (although I don't know if this would be wise).

Are there any non-anticonvulsant drugs that have been approved for use specifically with anticonvulsants - not just lamotrigine - to treat myoclonus arising from the use of said anticonvulsants, or are they incompatible for some reason? I'm aware that most drugs used to treat myoclonus are anticonvulsants, but I don't believe that all are (although do correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treatment of Myoclonus

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3899494/?tool=pmcentrez

Caviness JN. Treatment of Myoclonus. Neurotherapeutics. 2014;11(1):188-200. doi:10.1007/s13311-013-0216-3.

This article offers a concise and fairly exhaustive approach to the treatment of Myoclonus of any cause. If you look at Figure 3 (the treatment algorithm), there is a specific pathway for the treatment of drug-induced (Symptomatic) Myoclonus. The actual treatment - and any drugs that might be used - depends on the classification:

> cortical;
>   cortical–subcortical;
>   subcortical–nonsegmental;
>   segmental;
>   peripheral.

The ultimate treatment depends on this classification and is outlined in the article. The list of specific medications that may be used - anticonvulsants as well as other medications - is listed in the treatment algorithm.

The medications include:

> Levetiracetam, Piracetam, and Related Compounds; Sodium Valproate; Clonazepam; Zonisamide, Primidone, and Miscellaneous Agents (these are not anti-seizure medications)

Of these only a couple are specifically listed as add-on agents:

> Primidone and phenobarbital can be useful as add-on therapy